# Error 403.14 when use empty route [Route("")] in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm currently working on MVC5 application I have a controller like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("licence")]
[RoleAuthorize(Role.Administrator, Role.Partner)]
public class LicencesController
    {
        [Route("")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
         {
              // code to get model ready
              return View(model);
         }
    }
```

now when I call action index I get  **HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden** but when to change the routing of index action make it

```
        [Route("list")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
```

everything works fine, strangely when run the same code at another PC it works fine and no need to change action route.

I'm using razor views and IIS Express

What may be causing this issue?

Comment: Clean cookies (weird..) and try again.

Comment: @OrelEraki is not working I got the same result

Comment: Did you use any ReSharper Refactoring ?

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker Yes, I do use ReSharper, but I don't think that I made any Refactoring on purpose, however, I can run the same code at another machine smoothly without any problems (the other machine have ReSharper installed too)

Comment: @MohamedBadr Only asking because it happened to me before where the refactoring changed the routing parameters RegisterRoute

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker I use source control and checked the history nothing changed with RegisterRoute, but thanks for the hint